# Mapping int to float?

Tags: c, matlab, bit-manipulation

I want to implement a mapping from integer to float, but my low-level knowledge is a little bit rusty. The mapping is described in this paper :

1. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.124.8968&rep=rep1&type=pdf
2. [http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lcpfpv/](http://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Eisenburg/lcpfpv/)

> **3.2 Mapping to Integer**
>
> We could compute prediction residuals via floating-point
> subtraction, however this might cause underflow with irreversible
> loss of information that precludes reconstruction of>
> the actual value. Instead, as in [7, 22], we map the predicted
> and actual floats p and f to their sign-magnitude binary
> integer representation. On platforms implementing signmagnitude
> integer arithmetic, we could now simply compute
> integer residuals via subtraction, however most current platforms
> implement two’s complement arithmetic. To address
> this, we map the sign-magnitude representation to unsigned
> integers by flipping either the most significant bit (for positive
> floats) or all bits (for negative floats). The result is a
> monotonic mapping of floats to unsigned integers that preserves
> ordering and even linearity of differences for floats
> with the same sign and exponent. This approach is also
> similar to [16], however we benefit by allowing a carry to
> propagate from mantissa to exponent in case p and f are
> close but separated by an exponent boundary, which would
> be signaled as a large misprediction in [16].

There is also some C sample code, but i'm not quite sure, if i copied the right part:

```
typedef float            F32;
typedef int              I32;
typedef unsigned int    U32;

I32 exponentPred = (((U32&)floatnum) & 0x7F800000) >> 23;
I32 signPred = (((U32&)floatnum) & 0x80000000) == 0x80000000;
I32 mantissaPred = (((U32&)floatnum) & 0x007FFFFF);
```

So my questions are :

1. Can you explain me, what he is doing in the last 3 lines. I'd like to understand it on the binary level.
2. Is this the code to map floats to integers ?
3. How i can do the mapping in matlab ?

Thanks,
plasmido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0x80000000` is `1000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`

`0x7F800000` is `0111111 10000000 00000000 00000000`

`0x007FFFFF` is `0000000 01111111 11111111 11111111`

Now assume you have a floating point variable with these digits, each char standing for one binary digit:

floatnum = `SEEEEEEE EMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM`

`((U32&)floatnum) & 0x7F800000` is `0EEEEEEE E0000000 0000000 00000000`

Finally do a right shift `>>23` to get

`0000000 0000000 0000000 EEEEEEEE`

`((U32&)floatnum) & 0x80000000` is `S0000000 00000000 0000000 00000000`

Thus selecting the sign.

Finally, the last line selects the mantissa:

`((U32&)floatnum) & 0x007FFFFF` is `00000000 0MMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM`

Basically, the code is splitting the float into the three parts, using a bitmask.

//Edit ugly solution removed, found a better solution in matlab:

```
raw = typecast( single(floatNum), 'uint32' )
exponentPred=bitget(raw,[31:-1:22])
signPred=bitget(raw,[32])]
mantissaPred=bitget(raw,[23:-1:1])
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`typecast`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) to get `raw`? `raw = typecast( single(floatNum), 'uint32' )`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know matlab but what is happening ( considering this as C code ) is :

```
(U32&)floatnum
```

it's a cast, the content of `floatnum` is interpreted as it would be of type `U32&`

```
((U32&)floatnum) & 0x7F800000
```

that's a bitwise AND between the result of the previous expression and a costant, a number, but expressed as an hex value ( it's just the same thing as a decimal number, but often times programmers prefer to express themselfs and constants as HEX values )

```
(((U32&)floatnum) & 0x7F800000) >> 23
```

shifts the bits representing the result of the previous expression by 23 positions, the effect is that you will drop everything is in those 23 bits and you start counting bits from the 24th one.

If you want to know more about those operators go [for the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) .

But I think that it's important , if you want to understand this specific example, to outline the fact that:

- a `float` type it's often time a placeholder for a more specific [`IEEE 754`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) type, the difference between using a generic floating point representation or an `IEEE 754` is that in the second case you have a well defined representation, in other words given a 32 bit wide IEEE 754 type, you know what bits are representing what ( see the wiki for the bitmask )
- the given HEX constants are just representing special values that helps you to extract or mask out the bits that you want ( try to convert those constant in binary and apply the `&` operator )

Answer (score 0):

The code is separating the [single precision floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) into it's components as defined by the [IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985). One way to do it in MATLAB uses `num2hex` to split up the float into chunks of 4 bits, allowing easy conversion to a binary string:

```
f = 1.23456;
h = num2hex(f);
b = reshape(dec2bin(hex2dec(h'),4).',1,[])
```

Another way uses `typecast` to convert into an integer type suitable for `dec2bin` without changing the underlying data:

```
b = dec2bin(typecast(f,'uint64'),64);
```

Then you can pull out the sign, exponent and mantissa.  For example, a **double** has 1 bit for sign (`s`), 11 bits for exponent (`e`), and 52 bits for the significand (`m`):

```
s = b(1)

doubleBias = 1023;
e = bin2dec(b(2:12)) - doubleBias

fbin = str2num(b(64:-1:13).').'
m = sum(fbin.*2.^-(52:-1:1))
```

The number is then reassembled by:

```
num = (-1)^s * (1+m) * 2^e
```

For a **single** precision `float` (e.g. `f=single(1.23456);`), get `b` the same way as above (specifying 32 bits if using `typecast`), then extract the parts by:

```
s = b(1)
floatBias = 127;
e = bin2dec(b(2:9)) - floatBias
fbin = str2num(b(32:-1:10).').'
m = sum(fbin.*2.^-(23:-1:1))
```